# Fail to Join multiple dlink on different Database

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to join three different databases, two of which I already had a link to join, and when I select `db2_booking`, I get the data, and when I select `bd1_uaa`, I get the data from database

```
SELECT * FROM dblink('db2_booking','SELECT fullname FROM passenger_booking_details') 
AS DATA(fullname VARCHAR);
```

this works

```
SELECT * FROM dblink ('bd1_uaa','SELECT passenger_type_name  FROM passenger_types') AS DATA(passenger_type_name VARCHAR);
```

and this works

but this doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM dblink
('db2_booking, bd1_uaa','SELECT fullname, passenger_type_name 
 FROM passenger_booking_details AS b JOIN passenger_types AS p ON p.id=b.passenger_type_id') 
AS DATA(fullname VARCHAR, passenger_type_name VARCHAR);
```

I am using postgres

error

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  missing "=" after "db2_booking," in connection info string
SQL state: 08001
```

Comment: Of course that doesn't work. You would have to make two separate dblink calls and have the local system join the results.  Better yet, use FDW.